# ng-repeat twice won´t display

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Hi I have two different list which I want to display. I was wondering how to use ng-repeat twice to get them printed.
This is the HTML page:

```
<div>
    <div>Search: <input ng-model="query" placeholder="filter"></div> 
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="doc in documents | filter:query | state in statusofdoc"  ng-click="selectedDocument(doc)"  ><a href="#/documents/{{doc}}">{{doc}}</a>{{state}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This thing just display the doc but does not display the state. How to get ng-repeat run for both?

Comment: You need two different lists. You can't repeat like this.

Comment: I want to print it next to each other ? Would you recommend using a table instead ?

Comment: Please tell us why you need to iterate through `statusofdoc` and also what kind of data you are handling.

Comment: Why don't you add the status to the document object so you only need to repeat once?

Comment: I need to iterate through statusofdoc because it will tell me the status of the document (eg new/reviewed/old/) Both the status and doc are string

Comment: Document object contains status, docName, text.

Comment: If the document object contains the status why do you need another list? And if I am correct in my assumption then you can access the status like so {{doc.status}}, and only need to repeat the documents list. If I am not correct you need to add more detail to the question to help explain what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: From a list of document object i extracted the name/status into two different list documents and statusofdoc respectively which is stored in a linkedhashmap

Comment: @JaredReeves What you said makes sense